# Improve performance of sshfs for a lot of small files

Tags: files, filesystems, sshfs

Mounting a network filesystem backed by `sshfs` show very slow performance when trying to write a lot of relativity small files.

Is there any options to improve the situation?

The filesystem is mounted with the default options.

`sshfs user@host:/dir /moutpoint`

Comment: what version of sshfs are you running? maybe [sshfs 3.7](https://github.com/libfuse/sshfs/releases/tag/sshfs-3.7.0) might help